# Problem with artifacts when ploting TROPOMI data

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray, cartopy

Hello I experienced problems of artifact when ploting TROPOIMI SO2 data using PlateCarree() projection with cartopy, loading TROPOMI data via xarray.

The problem occurs when most of the data are around -180 and 180 longitude.

The problematic figure is attached below

[Image in Platcarre()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bWpf.png)

The same data are correctly plotted using Orthographic projection.

[Orthographic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDpNz.png)

So I assume that the problem is with plotting itself.

Here is the code

```
xr_data = xr.open_dataset(file_name, group='PRODUCT', 
                              engine='netcdf4', decode_coords=True)
xr_data=xr_data.set_coords(("latitude", "longitude"))
xr_data_so2 = xr_data['sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column'][0]
xr_data_so2=xr_data_so2 * xr_data_so2.multiplication_factor_to_convert_to_molecules_percm2
plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
ax = plt.axes(projection = ccrs.PlateCarree())

xr_data_so2.plot.pcolormesh(ax=ax, x='longitude',y='latitude', robust=True,shading='none',cmap='jet')
```

I tried to print it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This sounds more like a data problem than anything else. Can you show us the data?

Comment: Please show us the `xr_data_so2` and `xr_data_so2.longitude` it looks like an interpolation issue

Comment: It is sentinel 5p TROPOMI data. Here is the name and the link to download S5P_RPRO_L2__SO2____20200402T003553_20200402T021723_12792_03_020401_20230211T050104

https://s5phub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('9c0c33d7-3600-40cb-9799-8c581a4368c0')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the longitude convention. Perhaps you should use 0-360 range instead of -180+180

```
mask = xr_data_so2.longitude<0 
xr_data_so2.longitude[mask] = 360 + xr_data_so2.longitude[mask]
```

Comment: Great thank. I have modified this a bit but it was great help. Here is one line code of what solves the problem
xr_data_so2.longitude.values[xr_data_so2.longitude.values<0] = xr_data_so2.longitude.values[xr_data_so2.longitude.values<0]+360

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the `transform` keyword in the following line

```
xr_data_so2.plot.pcolormesh(ax=ax, x='longitude',y='latitude', robust=True,shading='none',cmap='jet', tranform = ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately. But thanks anyway.